# Magento Xss Prevention

Tags: magento

Is there any way to prevent xss attacks in magento? in my localhost i am just trying to check how to prevent xss attacks for example i am inserting a script when user register in magento, i am just shocked when inserting a whole script in the name field i am successfully registered my dashboard screenshot

[image]

after refreshing the page i got another screen[image]

I just want to prevent the user that no one can do like that.

Please help me prevent that types of attacks.

Comment: What's the version of Magento?

Comment: I am using magento-1.4.1.1 version.

Comment: it may be security leak in magento.

Comment: Tested your code judging from your screenshots on 1.5.0.1 on demo.magentocommerce.com no alert callback displayed.

Comment: Hi boomer it's shows at the time of registration while making an account in the first name and last name field i putting the script then it only shows. Thanks for reply...

Comment: Hi Boomer try this script at the time of registration in first name and last name field,then it definitely shows this error i also tested in various system and different magento installation.It's still showing this attack.

Comment: An address form XSS was fixed in the upgrade from 1.4.1.1 to 1.4.2.0. If you peruse the .diff files, you might be able to backport the fix. Otherwise the only way to fix this is to upgrade. This is from the 1.4.2.0 release notes.

Comment: The changes probably are in Magento version 1.4.2.0-beta1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Also, this may be a template problem. If your template doesn't properly escape user input, you end up with garbage in your database. I'm running 1.4.1.1 as well, but the input fields are filtered as follows:

```
<li class="wide">
    <label for="street_1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?></label>
    <div class="input-box">
        <input type="text" name="street[]" value="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" id="street_1" class="input-text required-entry" />
    </div>
</li>
```

The htmlEscape() function is supposed to take care of the nasties. On some templates, it was missing from search fields and you could get a verifiable XSS problem using it.

Comment: Have you gone in and checked the templates to see if they htmlEscape() your input fields? The various templates are in the Customer folder in your current template folder.

Answer (score 4):

Upgrading to the most recent version of any product is the best way to prevent XSS attacks. Young web applications are notorious for not taking these things seriously at first.

If you upgrade to the most recent version of Magento and are still running into the problem, I'd

1. Notify the vendor about the problem
2. Add a global model save listener that strips out html tags from fields in the specific models where you've found problems.

Comment: Always the correct and painful answer for PHP apps. From the 1.4.2.0 release notes -> **Fixed XSS issue in address form**

Comment: Hi Alan you are talking about making a modules to extend core file to prevent xss attacks,that is good idea but magento is not providing the security.

Comment: i just want to next magento release that is prevented form that types of attacks..